# pip3 failed with error code 1 in None when installing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2

Im working on a EC2 on linux:

**Machine:** Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-3885d854

```
python -V -> Python 2.7.14
python3 -V -> Python 3.4.8
pip -V -> pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
pip3 -V -> pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

And im trying to install pandas on python3 (i have no intentions on using python2 at all but it came installed by default)

When i do:

```
sudo pip3 install -U pandas
```

I get:

> Collecting pandas   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/01/803834bc8a4e708aedebb133095a88a4dad9f45bbaf5ad777d2bea543c7e/pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
>   Installing build dependencies ... error   Complete output from command
>   /usr/bin/python3.4 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user
>   --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-algfxof5 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=80044e51ec5bbf6c894ba0bc48d26a8c20a9ba629f4ca19ea26ecfcf87685f5f
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e1/820d941153923aac1d49d7fc37e17b6e73bfbd2904959fffbad77900cf92/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8fca9275c89964f13da985c3656cb00ba029d7f3916b37990927ffdf264e7926
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/70/9c0cb59667fa20ab95e8c9b9a45aa123396e882bac2dca6826181aef91c6/Cython-0.28.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=36c16bf39280fe857213d8da31c07a6179d3878c3dc2e435dce0974b9f8f0729
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bff36563f9d6a06a81ae232f49d2946c84c05e391a7dff057496033c79507860
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4eac5f2f624c5e7eecbdb51395ff39a099c48cab607a158f16f288c6fe39a2b3
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/ee/f65826b2880f67652c21326565b4c166c7cdb1019f84b82af65e625475cd/numpy-1.13.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=838e48df3703c8747f355cd6386e0680b906a2f7b2bbd304e8a2d531692484ce:
>   Double requirement given: numpy==1.12.1 from
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4eac5f2f624c5e7eecbdb51395ff39a099c48cab607a158f16f288c6fe39a2b3
>   (already in numpy==1.9.3 from
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bff36563f9d6a06a81ae232f49d2946c84c05e391a7dff057496033c79507860,
>   name='numpy')
>        ---------------------------------------- Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user
>   --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-algfxof5 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=80044e51ec5bbf6c894ba0bc48d26a8c20a9ba629f4ca19ea26ecfcf87685f5f
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e1/820d941153923aac1d49d7fc37e17b6e73bfbd2904959fffbad77900cf92/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8fca9275c89964f13da985c3656cb00ba029d7f3916b37990927ffdf264e7926
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/70/9c0cb59667fa20ab95e8c9b9a45aa123396e882bac2dca6826181aef91c6/Cython-0.28.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=36c16bf39280fe857213d8da31c07a6179d3878c3dc2e435dce0974b9f8f0729
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/1b/a1717502572587c724858862fd9b98a66105f3a3443225bda9a1bd16ee14/numpy-1.9.3-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=bff36563f9d6a06a81ae232f49d2946c84c05e391a7dff057496033c79507860
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/64/c6c1c24ff4dbcd789fcfdb782e343ac23c074f6b8b03e818ff60eb0f937f/numpy-1.12.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=4eac5f2f624c5e7eecbdb51395ff39a099c48cab607a158f16f288c6fe39a2b3
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/ee/f65826b2880f67652c21326565b4c166c7cdb1019f84b82af65e625475cd/numpy-1.13.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=838e48df3703c8747f355cd6386e0680b906a2f7b2bbd304e8a2d531692484ce"
>   failed with error code 1 in None

Ive try with different a billilion thing and cant get to a real answer.

--EDIT:

Already tried the `--no-cache-dir` flag. The problem persist.

Already tried `sudo -H pip3 install pandas` too. The problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

it is picking from cache, please try adding this `--no-cache-dir` and install

Can you give this a try as well

```
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```